How to retain values selected using kendo multiselect upon moving to next page
I have a multipage form in angular in which I am using kendo framework and in the first page I'm using kendo multiselect for selecting options and upon goin to second page and coming back to the first page the options which is selected in multiselect previously is not retained and it is getting reset how can I retain values??
I used form group for storing the values but it did not work

please share a minmal code stackblitz with the issue replicated, usually, we should not destroy the form, the values will get retained!
